# Updating a resource model after saving a new model instance and before transitioning to route in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ember.js, routes

Using Ember, we have a list of shoes which is fetched from a database. These are listed at '/shoes.

```
this.resource('shoes', function() {
  this.route('new');
  this.route('show', {path: ':shoe_id'});
  this.route('edit', {path: ':shoe_id/edit'});
});
```

Only the first 10 shoes in the MongoDB collection are listed in the view, as specified in our webb API. When creating a new shoe (using the nested route 'new'), and transitioning back to '/shoes', the new shoe is added to the current 'shoes' model.

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    save: function() {
      this.get('model').save();
      this.transitionToRoute('shoes');
    }
  }
});
```

This results in a list of 11 shoes. In other words, it does not use the route and make a new API call. Instead, it is added to the current list of shoes in the model. When refreshing the page, the result is rendered as intended, fetching the 10 first records of the DB collection.

We would like to make the ’transitionToRoute’ execute the route and re-fetch the model instead of just adding it to the current model. We have seen a few examples of how ’this.refresh()’ and ’this.reload()’ can be used inside the controller's 'model' scope body but these examples have not worked for us.

Is it possible to make a ’transitionToRoute’ refresh the model with new database values using the 'shoes' route?

Comment: are you using ember-data? or what does your shoes route look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you wrote, I'm guessing you're trying to use pagination and only want the first 10 shoes to be listed on your `/shoes` route?

If so, the "Ember Way" is to always keep all your models in sync and never have to do special work just to get the view to update artificially.  In this case, Ember has a local store of `shoes` where it initially has 10 items.  Then you add one more, it gets saved both the database and to the Ember local store and so now Ember thinks (correctly) that you have 11 shoes.  Just because Mongo returns 10 shoes doesn't mean your entire data set is 10 shoes.

So, the best way to handle this situation is to have your view display an accurate projection of your underlying model data.  In other words, don't tell your view to display "all shoes". Tell it to display a "filtered list of all shoes"!

In practice, I've seen two types of filtering on `ArrayController`.  One is just to return the first `n` values.  For that use good old javascript `slice` ([See MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)).  The second is to use the Ember `filter` function. [See Ember Docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/enumerables/#toc_filtering).

Ultimately, your controller would something like this:

**Shoes Controller:**

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend( PaginatorClientSideMixin, {

    shoesFilteredOption1: function() {
        return this.get('arrangedContent') // 'arrangedContent' is the sorted list of underlying content; assumes your backing model is the DS.RecordArray of shoes
            // this use of slice takes an array and returns the first 10 elements
            .slice( 0, 10 );

        // we depend on 'arrangedContent' because everytime this changes, we need to recompute this value
    }.property('arrangedContent')

    shoesFilteredOption2: function() {
        return this.get('arrangedContent') // 'arrangedContent' is the sorted list of underlying content; assumes your backing model is the DS.RecordArray of shoes
            // here we're filtering the array to only return "active" shoes
            .filter( function(item, index, self ) {
                if (item.isActive) { return true; }
            })
    }.property('arrangedContent')

});
```

Then on your Handlebars template read from `shoesFilteredOption1` instead of `content` or `model`.